# IPN works for "guest" payments but not paypal account holders

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I have a subscription payment set up for my website. When a user clicks to subscribe, they are taken to a Paypal page with the option to log in and pay through their Paypal account or to continue basically as a "guest" and enter their credit card information. When a payment is made, it is supposed to open extra features on the user's account.

When making test payments, payments made as a "guest" would go through and be relayed to my site to open the extra features for that user. However, any time I log in to my personal Paypal account to pay, the payment itself will go through but it is not being recognized by the website to unlock the additional features.

We have looked for settings that may need to be changed, such as enabling PDT, but that did not help. The website is receiving all the proper information from "guests" but I don't understand why someone logging into their Paypal account would be any different and cause this problem. I don't want people to be paying money and not getting what they are expecting. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When unlocking the extra features, is the redirection URL included in the code? I would suggest to use IPN to assist with this feature.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Do note that for subscription payment, it might take a few hours for the profile to be active on the PayPal site.